# select records order by a field and get SUM group by the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get records ordered by a field, say, project, and also calculate some fields grouped by the same field.

E.g.

```
Project    |    Worked By      |    Hours
------------------------------------------------
Data Entry |    Rakesh Malakar |    40.0
Data Entry |    Najar Man      |    25.0
                               |    65.0
Editing    |    Henry Bdr.     |    20.0
Editing    |    Jack Pd.       |    15.5
                               |    35.5
```

I have a similar data set on the database. All I need is just the sum grouped by `project` field.

I tried the query:

```
SELECT project, user as worked_by, hours, SUM(hours) as project_sum_hours
FROM project_hours
ORDER BY project
GROUP BY project
```

The query only returns an aggregated record for each `project` field.

Comment: `GROUPING SET`s anyone? If your database don't implement this *standard* SQL clause, then you'll need to `UNION ALL` two subqueries.

Comment: `order by` comes after `group by`

Comment: It sounds like you want [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: If appropriate, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Remove hours from select clause and add project and user in group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need `UNION ALL` to get the results as you want:

```
SELECT project, user as worked_by, SUM(hours) as project_sum_hours
FROM project_hours
GROUP BY project, user
UNION ALL
SELECT project, NULL, SUM(hours) as project_sum_hours
FROM project_hours
GROUP BY project
ORDER BY project, (worked_by IS NULL) DESC;
```

`ROLLUP` is handy, but will produce more rows than you want.  And MySQL doesn't (yet?) support `GROUPING SETS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html), to calculate super-aggregates.

Try the following:

```
SELECT project, 
       user as worked_by, 
       SUM(hours) as hours 
FROM project_hours
GROUP BY project, worked_by WITH ROLLUP
```